# Pandoc: Problem with incorrect section numbers in generated DOCX chapter

Tags: docx, pandoc, sections

I am using pandoc to generate my thesis chapters.
When I generate individual chapters, I am using the

```
Chapter 4: <Title of Chapter> {#chapter-4}
=======================
```

syntax.

In the generated HTML and the EPUB and PDF documents, the sections are correctly numbered as 4.1, 4.2, etc, but in the generated DOCX document the sections are numbered 1.1, 1.2 etc.
In the 'full thesis' DOCX document all section numbers are correct.

Does anyone know what I can do about this? It's pretty much the same pandoc call across formats so I am not sure what options I can tweak!

Command I am using to generate chapter 4 DOCX (where numbering is incorrect):

```
pandoc src/index.md src/chapter-4.md --output=./out/docx/chapter-4.docx -s --toc --toc-depth=4 --filter=pandoc-citeproc --self-contained --number-sections --number-offset=3
```

Command I am using to generate chapter 4 PDF (where numbering is correct):

```
pandoc src/index.md src/chapter-4.md --output=./out/pdf/chapter-4.pdf -s --toc --toc-depth=4 --filter=pandoc-citeproc --self-contained --number-sections --number-offset=3 -t html5
```

Command I am using for whole thesis DOCX (where numbering is correct):

```
pandoc src/index.md src/frontmatter.md src/chapter-1.md src/chapter-2.md src/chapter-3.md src/chapter-4.md src/chapter-5.md  src/chapter-7.md  src/chapter-8.md src/bibliography.md --toc --number-sections --self-contained --toc-depth=2 --filter=pandoc-citeproc --output=./out/docx/thesis.docx
```